# Unable to add facebook plugin to phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, facebook-login, phonegap-facebook-plugin

I refered to this [link](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/README.md) and tried to add the facebook plugin into my phonegap project by input this command

```
cordova -d plugin add C:\Users\user\Desktop\Tinder-like Marketplace\plugins --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
```

but it return me

```
No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".
No version specified for C:\Users\user\Desktop\Tinder-like, retrieving version from config.xml
Attempting to use npm info for C:\Users\user\Desktop\Tinder-liketo choose a compatible release
Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/com/phonegap.tinderlike
```

Anyone know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, I got this error because I never install the git and cordova and the path is wrong. After the installation and change the path to https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin, then everything work fine.